# Can I splice hard PVC with soft PVC?

Tags: water, pvc

I am splicing a PVC pipe identical to the pipe on the left of the image. I will insert 3 inches and use a pair of joints like the one that appears on the right of the image.

Hence I'm guessing it's ideal if I splice using the exact same pipe, the one on the left.

But during an experimental dry run before the actual cut+splicing, the pipe (on the left) and the joint (on the right) were already quite fused. There was no cement in sight, and I sanded to bevel, and wiped with a rag before insertion. They were so fused it took a pair of pipe pliers to separate them. With the actual pipe, I won't have the luxury of twisting with pliers to undo the dry run.

[image: hard PVC, soft PVC, and a joint]

This makes me wonder whether it would be alright to use the soft pipe in the middle of the image for splicing. This setup is under the sun 365 days a year, but all three are, I presume, appropriate for full-on weather exposure.

Questions:

1. Can I use the pipe in the center to splice a pipe that looks like the one on the left (using a pair of the joints on the right)?
2. I am still not sure whether I'll need 3 or 3.25 or 3.5 inches, and so I'd really like to do a dry run. What can I do to make separating a dry run easier?
3. In the past I've skipped using the PVC primer and went straight for the PVC cement. The result is solid. Does using a primer soften PVC so much to make it easier to push the two sides harder and make sure they have entered all the way?

Comment: Depending on the layout/configuration, you may want or need an expansion joint, since the sun goes away 365 nights per year, and things normally get cooler and shrink then.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using electrical conduit as plumbing pipe? The listing issues go both ways on this one...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Ok.. maybe this is the issue then. I know that the pipe in the middle of the picture and the fitting on the right are for plumbing. The one on the left is from existing stock that looks identical to common plumbing pipes. How did you determine that the PVC on the left of the figure is meant for electrical work, not for plumbing? Do these inscriptions identify it as such?

Comment: The pipe looks gray in your picture- that would be electric conduit- is it actually white schedule 40 PVC meant for water lines ?

Comment: Use _WHITE_ PVC plumbing pipe for plumbing applications, _NOT_ grey PVC designed for electrical applications. i.e. don't use any of this for moving water.

Comment: Plumbing schedule 80 is also gray/grey. So you have to look at the text on the outside to be sure.

Comment: Evidently form the fragment of the text visible,  this is DWV pipe, though that would be more clear if more of the text were showing.

Comment: a comment on to how to do it no special fittings, get a pan of boiling water and dip the pvc in the water at least 2 diameters deep, press the pvc to the side of the pan every couple of seconds while stirring the pvc in the hot water when the pvc is like soft rubber you are ready to either stretch over the other pipe or compress inside the other pipe. I work the 2 pipes until I have about 1-1/2 pipe diameters stretched (stretching works better for me) let it cool. Separate , add primer, glue and assemble as good as factory connector works great on conduit I have used for water not flex though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix the schedule 40 PVC (rigid) and the flexible conduit legally. You would need different fittings to adapt the different pipes as mentioned in the comment by @Ecnerwal.

A dry run is not necessary- for the very reason you experienced. If you push that coupling dry all the way onto the pipe it will be very difficult to get it off. The pipe glue actually acts as a lubricant so the fittings slide on the pipe easily (but only for a short time- the glue sets fast).

Typically this is done by measuring the needed piece of pipe. I can't tell what size your conduit is, but, you can measure from pipe to pipe and subtract about 1/4" **for each end** (the repair piece of conduit will not fully reach the existing pipe because of the stop inside the coupling). If anything, cut it a bit short- conduit is very forgiving.

Often with conduit priming is not necessary. I would say it depends on what type of glue you are using. If it is regular clear PVC cement then you would be better to prime it- priming will give a better bond.

Comment: "_pipe glue actually acts as a lubricant_" Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Does using a primer enhance the lubricant effect? Is primer+cement better at lubricating than cement alone? Would pouring hot water on both parts before welding soften them, even a little, to make the insertion easier?

Comment: Primer will make negligible difference in it's slide-ablility. I have never used hot water to soften the pipe. If you don't have the room to flex between your 2 existing pipes to fit the couplings then you have another issue all together. Just saw your other comment- you have PVC conduit not water pipe- conduit is not really rated for water- maybe you are OK with the minimal pressure you have but, it is not designed to be used under pressure.